# Uniform convergence:$g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2^k-2}\sqrt{1-x^{2^k}},\ $when$\ \ x\in[0,1].$

Tags: functions

This question comes from a problem of *Art of Problem Solving*. The problem says that:

> Let $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}+x^2f(x^2)$. Find $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)dx$.

I found that $g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2^k-2}\sqrt{1-x^{2^k}}$ satisfies the equation. But I can't prove that the series converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.

At the beginning, I tried to do piecewise calculation$$g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x^{2^k-2}\sqrt{1-x^{2^k}}+\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}x^{2^k-2}\sqrt{1-x^{2^k}}.$$
Via *Wolfram Alpha*, I got $$x^{2^k-2}\sqrt{1-x^{2^k}}\sim\sqrt{2^kx},\ x^{2^k-2}\sqrt{1-x^{2^k}}<2^{\frac{k}{2}+\varepsilon}\sqrt x,\ \varepsilon>0.$$ But it's hard to keep going.

Comment: Have you tried to determine if the function $\varphi(x)=x^{2^{k+1}-4}.(1-x^{2^k})$ admits a maximum on [0, 1]. I passed the first term under the root and considered the expression under the square root alone. There seems to be a maximum for $x^{2^k}=\frac{2^{k+1}-4}{3.2^k-4}$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette I don't know how to use the thing to calculate.

Comment: To prove the uniform convergence of the series, studying the series $\sum_k \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |g_k(x)|$ can give the result. But I just looked and there doesn't seem to be uniform convergence. The limit of the general term is equal to 1.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette I get it.This way is a bit problematic.

Comment: $$
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]} \sum\limits_{k = N}^\infty  {x^{2^k  - 2} \sqrt {1 - x^{2^k } } }  \ge (2^{ - 1/2^N } )^{2^N  - 2} \sqrt {1 - (2^{ - 1/2^N } )^{2^N } }  = 2^{2/2^N } \frac{1}{{2\sqrt 2 }} \ge \frac{1}{{2\sqrt 2 }}
$$

Comment: source: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2763749

Comment: @Gary Thank you!

Comment: @cineel Thank you!